# Installing Ssl certificate spray

Tags: scala, ssl, spray

I'm trying to install self-signed certificate to the spray server.
I did like described in this post: 
[generate keystore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695297/importing-the-private-key-public-certificate-pair-in-the-java-keystore)
But on a income connection I see this exception:

```
[ERROR] [05/08/2016 11:07:12.896] [tracking-akka.actor.default-ispatcher-6] [akka://tracking/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/16] Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:92)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLEngineImpl.java:2038)
    at com.web3.tracking.SslConfiguration$$anonfun$sslEngineProvider$1.apply(SslConfiguration.scala:67)
    at com.web3.tracking.SslConfiguration$$anonfun$sslEngineProvider$1.apply(SslConfiguration.scala:66)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at spray.io.SSLEngineProviderCompanion$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(SslTlsSupport.scala:424)
    at spray.io.SSLEngineProviderCompanion$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(SslTlsSupport.scala:424)
```

Comment: Probably you need to install this on your JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html; alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179672/how-to-avoid-installing-unlimited-strength-jce-policy-files-when-deploying-an

Comment: @dk14 thanks you saved my day