# KeyStore.builder - type parameter for .crt files

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I'm writing code that would apply digital signature for a given file. I have .crt file and I need to build KeyStore instance using that file. The method I want to use is as follows:

```
 Builder newInstance(String **type**, Provider provider,
                File file, ProtectionParameter protection)
```

however I'm not sure what ***'type'*** should I specify If I use .crt file,
it may happen that I don't understand something as this is my first time when I deal with digital signatures, don't judge me in this case :-)

Thanks, cheers

Comment: Do you want to verify a signature ? or sign?

Comment: @MuhammadHamed I want to sign a document with that .crt file, sorry for the question, that's my first time when I deal with signatures or cryptography

Comment: What further as I know that you can use the pfx or PKCS#12 certificate stores to sign , which comes with .pfx or .p12. The signing process requires a private key do you have the keypairs related to this certificate.

Comment: @MuhammadHamed thanks for your support, I have .crt file and .pem file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can firstly build the JKS (java keystore file and use it) using the private key (.pem) and the certificate (.crt)

check this answer [Importing the private-key/public-certificate pair in the Java KeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695297/importing-the-private-key-public-certificate-pair-in-the-java-keystore)

then you can use this keystore to sign, here's how to load the new create java keystore file

```
KeyStore keystore  = KeyStore.getInstance(TYPE_OF_KEYSTORE);
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
```

and here's an example to digitally sign and verify

```
                           PrivateKey oPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(sAlias,null);


                           Provider p = keystore.getProvider();
                           // data to signed
                           byte[] data ="this is the just for test".getBytes();
                           // Signing the data
                           Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
                           sig.initSign(oPrivateKey);

                           sig.update(data);
                           byte[] signature = sig.sign(); // the digital signature

                           Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", p);
                           verifier.initVerify(oPublicCertificate);
                           verifier.update(data);
                           System.out.println("the verification result "+verifier.verify(signature));
```

http://muhammadhamed.blogspot.com/2010/04/accessing-ms-certificate-stores-in-java.html

I hope this could help!